# invoking certreq via powershell

Tags: powershell, certreq

I am trying to build tool which would renew expired certs and I am strugling with invoking certreq command:

this one is working:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Srvname -ScriptBlock {Set-Location -Path 'D:\'; $Out = cmd /c 2>&1 'certreq -q -f -new D:\cert\request_new.inf D:\cert\certreq.csr'}
```

but that one does not

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Srvname -ScriptBlock {Set-Location -Path 'D:\'; $Out = cmd /c 2>&1 'certreq -f -attrib "CertificateTemplate:WebServer" -submit D:\cert\certreq.csr D:\cert\request.cer'}
```

I think its because I need to accept the prompt from cert authority and that prompt does not show.

The script works localy when executing:

```
certreq -f -attrib "CertificateTemplate:WebServer" -submit D:\cert\certreq.csr D:\cert\request.cer
```

Do you have any ideas?

I have tried psexec but that didnt work either. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the `certreq.exe` documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn296456(v=ws.11).aspx):

```
-q      Use silent mode; suppress all interactive prompts.
```

Comment: yeah...i tried it :( this one does not work with `-attrib "CertificateTemplate:WebServer" -submit`